# Github search PRs opened by members of a team

Tags: api, github

Is there an easy way to search for a given github repository how many pull requests were created by members of a certain team without having to specify the entire list of its members ?

For some context:

My goal would be to collect how many PRs my team is making to a "monolith shared code" and use it as a KPI (in a sense that the fewer PRS we have the better!)